# pass array as function parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I encountered an error while coding in javascript. I want to pass an array as a function parameter from main function to another function, do operations in function and the return edited array.

However, as far as I understood, when I di\o this 
`var1 = function_1(var2)` where `var2` is an array, it doesn't actually pass the array to a function.

I want to do this with standard JavaScript library.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will pass the array. Why do you think it does not?

Comment: Is there a PHP part to this question seems like just JS?

Comment: Doesn't pass? What made you think so?? [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gbogx5f6/).

Comment: @CodeiSir when I put an `alert()` in the function for test, it doesn't alert my array. instead, it alerts undefined or just nothing.

Comment: I added an answer showing the working code

Comment: @GrigorBezirganyan, please add your "not working" code.

Comment: @NinaScholz It worked already, however thank you for your will to help )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To demonstrate how it would work:

```js
var var2 = [1,2,3]
var var1 = function_1(var2)

function function_1(a) {
  alert(a)
  return a
}
```